# Motivate why we may calculate $P[X<Y]$ as $\int_\infty^\infty P[X<Y|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy$

Tags: probability-theory

Given two independent random variables $X $ and $Y $ with continuous densities we know that there exists a regular conditional distribution $P[X<Y|Y=y] $, and futher that the regular conditional distribution has density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y) $.

How do we motivate that $P[X<Y]=\int_\infty^\infty P[X<Y|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy$. This looks like a generalization of the discrete case where we may write $\{X<Y\}$ as the disjoint union $\bigcup _{k \in Z } \{X<k\} \cap \{Y=k \}$ and then use the countable additivity of $P $ to conclude that $$P[X<Y]=\sum_{k \in Z }P[\{X<k\} \cap \{Y=k \}] $$  (And of course for every $k$, $P[\{X<k\} \cap \{Y=k \}]=P[X<y|Y=k]P[Y=k]$ )

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of the very general "double expectation theorem" of conditional expectations:

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of events, and $Z$ a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable such that either $Z$ is non-negative or $Z \in L^1(P)$.
>   Then
>   $$
> E[Z] = E[E[Z \mid \mathcal{G}]].
> $$

As a special case, using the fact that a probability of an event is the same as the expected value of the indicator function of that event, we obtain

> **Corollary.**
>   Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of events, and $A \in \mathcal{F}$ an event.
>   Then
>   $$
> P(A) = E[P(A \mid \mathcal{G})].
> $$

If we have a random variable $Y$, then conditioning on $Y$ means (by definition) conditioning on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$.
In particular,
$$
P(A)
= E[P(A \mid Y)]
$$
for any event $A$.
Even more specifically, in your case we can obtain the general formula
$$
P(X < Y)
= E[P(X < Y \mid Y)].
$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are both discrete, then this reduces to the usual formula:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X < Y)
&= E[P(X < Y \mid Y)] \\
&= \sum_y P(X < Y \mid Y = y) P(Y = y) \\
&= \sum_y P(X < Y, Y = y).
\end{aligned}
$$
Moreover, if $X$ and $Y$ are both absolutely continuous with joint density $f_{X, Y}$ and marginal densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, respectively, then one can show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X < Y)
&= E[P(X < Y \mid Y)] \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(X < Y \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) \, dy.
\end{aligned}
$$
This is what you asked about, and it is because $P(X < Y \mid Y)$ is the $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable $g(Y)$, where $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function given by
$$
g(y) = P(X < Y \mid Y = y) = \int_0^y f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) \, dx.
$$
Here $f_{X \mid Y}$ is the conditional density
$$
f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)
= \begin{cases} \frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} &\text{if $f_Y(y) > 0$} \\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks this is a very good post! And I now get the crucial idea with the "double expectation theorem". What still isn't clear for me is this: I have $P[X\in B|Y=y] $ defined as stochastic kernel and I have the result that given the conditions in the queston this stochastic kernel has density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y) $. But as you have written we would need the density of the stochastic kernel of $P[X-Y \in B|Y=y] $.

Comment: and that this density is the same!

Comment: @MrFranzén $P(X < Y \mid Y = y) = P(X < y \mid Y = y)$, so it *is* of the form $P(X \in B \mid Y = y)$. I was thinking about including this simplification in the answer when writing it, but I decided to keep the $X < Y$ form since that's what you had in your question.

Comment: And how do you define $P(X<Y|Y=y) $?

Comment: @MrFranzén for any Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ the random variable $P((X, Y) \in B \mid Y)$ is $Y$-measurable, so it can be written as $P((X, Y) \in B \mid Y) = g(Y)$ for some measurable function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This $g$ is precisely the definition of $P((X, Y) \in B \mid Y = y) := g(y)$

Comment: exactly but then I need to show that $P((X,Y) \in B|Y=y) $ has density $f_{X|Y } $

Comment: @MrFranzén you just need to show that $P(X < Y \mid Y = y) = P(X < y \mid Y = y)$ in this case

Comment: Okey but how would you do that?

Comment: @MrFranzén for example, let $g(y, z) = P(X < z \mid Y = y)$ (so $g(Y, z) = P(X < z \mid Y)$). Define $h(y) = g(y, y) = P(X < y \mid Y = y)$. Show that $h(Y) = P(X < Y \mid Y)$, which will imply that $P(X < y \mid Y = y) = g(y, y) = P(X < Y \mid Y = y)$ (all equalities are almost surely equalities)

Comment: okey so following your argument i get that I have to show that $P[\{Y \in (-\infty,X)\}|\sigma(X)](\omega) $ equals $P[\{(X,Y) \in C \}|\sigma(X)](\omega)$, where $C=\{(x,y):y<x \}$, clearly the two sets we are measuring are equal and thus the question will be: given the two regular conditional distributions of $X $ respectively $(X,Y) $ given $\sigma (X) $ (ie the stochastic kernels associated with them) are their measures at the point $\omega $ equivalent?

Comment: and I don't know how to argue here.

Comment: I see now that I had muddled up the concepts here in the comments. Your aswer is perfectly satisfactorily. I will accept it but also try to write a short anser myself that might help others. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Reading my own post two monts later I would like to add the following for any future viewer of this post.

To derive 
$$P[X<Y]=\int P[X<Y|Y=y] f_(y)dy$$ 
we do the following.

$P[X<Y]=\int P[X<Y|Y](\omega)P(d \omega )=\int P[X<Y|Y=y]P_Y(dy)=\int P[X<Y|Y=y]f_Y(y)dy$

where the first equality is the double expectation formula, the second the definition of conditional expectation of $1_{X<Y} $ given that  $Y=y $ [See Definition 4 on p. 262 in Shiryaev's Probability 1 (2016)] and the third equality the definition of a density, $P_Y=f_Y dy $. None of this uses the independence of $X $ and $Y $.

If we also assumes independence we may use the following result which may be found on p.263 in Shiryaev's Probability 1 (2016) to get $P[X<Y]=\int P[X<y] f_(y)dy$

> If $X,Y $ are independent and $\phi $ is a $\mathcal B(R^2) $
>   measurable function such that $E[|\phi(X,Y) |]<\infty $ then  $$\int E[\phi(X,Y)|Y=y]P_Y(dy)=\int E[\phi(X,y)]P_Y(dy)$$

We simply let $\phi(x,y)=1_{\{x<y\}}(x,y)$.